# NavigationComponents - NavigationDrawer not working in java [Bug]

Tags: java, android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have created a new project with navigation drawer in java and the selection of the items in the drawer menu are not switching fragments

I have tried implementing

```
  @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_gallery);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_send:
            Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_send);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But is not navigating between fragments, the drawer menu does not select any of the fragments, is this a bug from java side ?
[image]

As you can see at the gif, I open the drawer and wherever I click Im not going to the fragment it suppose to go, this is a new project doing

**new - Activity - Navigation Drawer activity**

This is in Java and the navigation is not working, I think is a bug

I tried without implementing `onNavigationItemSelected` and also does not work

This is the rest of the class

```
public class DisplayScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_screen);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_gallery:
                Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_gallery);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_send:
                Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_send);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This article will help walk you through the process - https://medium.com/android-hunger/how-to-implement-navigation-drawer-in-your-android-app-with-an-example-48e08530339f

Comment: the thing is that this uses navigation components which hides the fragment transactions behind

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using Navigation Components and item clicks don't work.